# Root Unlocked Mi A2 without fastboot

Tags: adb, rooting, android-11

I have a mi A2 device that I unlocked it and flashed TWRP on it. I flashed TWRP on both slots and everything was ok.
After that, my USB board or charging board damaged for unknown reasons and the repairman could not fix it, Also, its charging board is very rare in my area and I can't find it.
So, my phone is never detected by PC but it can be charged, and I can't use fastboot commands.

A few days ago without knowing that DotOS has dedicated recovery, I flashed it with TWRP on slot A, and now I can't use TWRP on slot A anymore. But I think the TWRP is still installed on the slot B.
I really need root my device, so please help me.

1- Is there anyway to change slots without fastboot?

2- Can I install TWRP from anyway other than fastboot?

I tried to install TWRP zip file from DotOS recovery but it does not accept any file from internal storage (/storage/emulated/0/) and throw Permission denied exception. (I saw it from logs).

I can use adb commands with wireless debugging feature in android 11.

Comment: Is DotOS custom ROM? ask maintainer for backdoor